# Outlook 2010 Error

Tags: exchange, outlook, outlook-2010

I'm running Outlook 2010 SP1 on Windows 7 x64 SP1, and I'm getting an error message saying

> "Your Microsoft Exchange administrator has blocked the version of Outlook that you are using. Contact your administrator for assistance."

I'm still able to log into my account using Outlook Web Access (OWA), so I know that my account is working just fine. Outlook 2010 with Service Pack 1 is the standard for Windows 7 client systems at this organization, and other people are able to access their e-mail just fine. When my account was initially configured, I was able to use Outlook for a couple of days, and then it suddenly stopped working, providing only the above error message.

Do you have any ideas on what I should look into to resolve this problem? Is there any information I can obtain on the client side that will help the Exchange folks investigate the issue further? Is there any verbose logging I can enable, or diagnostic logging in Outlook?

Cheers

Comment: Contact your administrator.

Answer (score 5):

Statement: I'm still able to log into my account using Outlook Web Access (OWA), so I know that my account is working just fine.

Retort: Of course it is, because the message you're getting doesn't say anything about your account being unavailable or disabled/locked out. The message very clearly states that the version of Outlook that you're using has been blocked.

Q: Do you have any ideas on what I should look into to resolve this problem?

A: Yes. Speak to your Exchange administrator and tell him/her the message you're getting regarding your Outlook client.

Q: Is there any information I can obtain on the client side that will help the Exchange folks investigate the issue further? Is there any verbose logging I can enable, or diagnostic logging in Outlook?

A: How could it not already be blatantly, painfully obvious what the problem is? What could additional logging/information tell you that you don't already know? Stop over thinking and over troubleshooting this. Every problem doesn't have to have a complex, mysterious cause. KIS applies to troubleshooting as much as it does to anything else. If your Exchange admins need any additional information beyond what the message states in order to "investigate the issue further" then they're probably not the right folks for that job.

I appreciate the fact that you want to give your admins as much information as possible, and I'm not picking on you, but too many times I see people going off on wild goose hunts while trying to resolve a problem when basic, logical, deductive reasoning is all that's needed to find a resolution. In your case, the message is very clear as to what the problem is. Give that info to your admins and let them address it.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty self explanatory. Exchange allows you to set a minimum client version to connect to the server with. It may be the admin set the client version incorrectly (as you are running fairly recent version of Outlook). This minimum can be set on a per-CAS basis or per mailbox on Exchange 2010

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335207.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This link should supply you with the troubleshooting steps you need: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924625